# how to make a hidden navigation bar visible on all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, navigation

I am having a bit of trouble and hopefully someone can help me out. Basically Ive created a child theme from a wordpress theme called Bigfoot by TBH and I'm able to go in and change what I need but the only thing that is preventing me at the moment is the ability to make the navigation bar stay on the page vs having to click on a menu button for it to open up.

As it is right now, you have to click on a menu button and then the navigation bar appears. I just want to remove the code/command telling the navigation to do that. I want the navigation to be displayed at all times and im not sure how or what you change. Ive tried removing and changing various tags but nothing seems to work. I was hoping someone here could give some insit or suggestions on how to either bypass that command or if anyone had information on how/what to remove to make the navigation bar stay on all pages.

You can view the theme by googling Bigfoot by TBH. Below is the code I believe is causing the navigation to only appear after the menu button is pressed. There is some javascript but the site is mostly run with css.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage BigFoot
 * @since BigFoot 1.0
 */
?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> <?php thb_html_class(); ?>>
    <head>
        <?php thb_head_meta(); ?>

        <title><?php thb_title(); ?></title>

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

        <?php thb_body_start(); ?>

        <div id="page">

            <?php thb_header_before(); ?>

            <header id="header">
                <?php thb_header_start(); ?>

                <div class="header-container">

                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <?php
                            $logo = thb_get_option('main_logo');
                            $logo_2x = thb_get_option('main_logo_retina');

                            if( !empty($logo['id']) && !empty($logo_2x['id']) ) : ?>
                            <?php $logo_metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($logo['id']); ?>
                            <style>
                                @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
                                    #logo {
                                        background-image: url('<?php echo thb_image_get_size($logo_2x['id'], 'full'); ?>');
                                        background-size: <?php echo $logo_metadata['width']; ?>px, <?php echo $logo_metadata['height']; ?>px;
                                    }

                                    #logo img { visibility: hidden; }
                                }
                            </style>

                            <?php endif;
                        ?>
                        <h1 id="logo">
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
                                <?php if( isset($logo['id']) && $logo['id'] != '' ) : ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo thb_image_get_size($logo['id'], 'full'); ?>" alt="">
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </h1>

                        <?php thb_nav_before(); ?>

                        <a href="#" id="nav-trigger">m</a>

                        <div class="nav-wrapper">
                            <nav id="main-nav" class="main-navigation primary">
                                <?php thb_nav_start(); ?>

                                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

                                <?php thb_nav_end(); ?>
                            </nav>

                            <nav id="mobile-nav" class="main-navigation primary">
                                <?php thb_nav_start(); ?>

                                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

                                <?php thb_nav_end(); ?>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <?php thb_nav_after(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="wrapper">
```

there is also this javascipt but im not entirely sure what it does. Im not sure where the problem is coming from. The theme is called Bigfoot by thb if you wanted to look at their site and use the developer tools to see if you can change the code. Within developer tools its as simple as turning a invisible tag, visible. But thats not changing anything after. I think somewhere within the code is a tag or class telling the navigation to only appear once a button is click.

```
>/*!
* jQuery Cycle2; ver: 20121219
* http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/
* Copyright (c) 2012 M. Alsup; Dual licensed: MIT/GPL
*/
(function(a){function c(){window.console&&console.log&&console.log("[cycle2] "+Array.prototype.join.call(arguments," "))}function d(a){return(a||"").toLowerCase()}"use strict";var b="20121219";a.fn.cycle=function(b){var e;return this.length===0&&!a.isReady?(e={s:this.selector,c:this.context},c("requeuing slideshow (dom not ready)"),a(function(){a(e.s,e.c).cycle(b)}),this):this.each(function(){var e,f,g,h,i=a(this);if(i.data("cycle.opts"))return;if(i.data("cycle-log")===!1||b&&b.log===!1||f&&f.log===!1)c=a.noop;c("--c2 init--"),e=i.data();for(var j in e)e.hasOwnProperty(j)&&/^cycle[A-Z]+/.test(j)&&(h=e[j],g=j.match(/^cycle(.*)/)[1].replace(/^[A-Z]/,d),c(g+":",h,"("+typeof h+")"),e[g]=h);f=a.extend({},a.fn.cycle.defaults,e,b||{}),f.timeoutId=0,f.paused=f.paused||!1,f.container=i,f._maxZ=f.maxZ,f.API=a.extend({_container:i},a.fn.cycle.API),f.API.log=c,f.API.trigger=function(a,b){return f.container.trigger(a,b),f.API},i.data("cycle.opts",f),i.data("cycle.API",f.API),f.API.trigger("cycle-bootstrap",[f,f.API]),f.API.addInitialSlides(),f.API.preInitSlideshow(),f.slides.length&&f.API.initSlideshow()})},a.fn.cycle.API={opts:function(){return this._container.data("cycle.opts")},addInitialSlides:function(){var b=this.opts(),c=b.slides;b.slideCount=0,b.slides=a(),c=c.jquery?c:b.container.find(c),b.random&&c.sort(function(){return Math.random()-.5}),b.API.add(c)},preInitSlideshow:function(){var b=this.opts();b.API.trigger("cycle-pre-initialize",[b]);var c=a.fn.cycle.transitions[b.fx];c&&a.isFunction(c.preInit)&&c.preInit(b),b._preInitialized=!0},postInitSlideshow:function(){var b=this.opts();b.API.trigger("cycle-post-initialize",[b]);var c=a.fn.cycle.transitions[b.fx];c&&a.isFunction(c.postInit)&&c.postInit(b)},initSlideshow:function(){var b=this.opts(),c=b.container;b.API.calcFirstSlide(),b.container.css("position")=="static"&&b.container.css("position","relative"),a(b.slides[b.currSlide]).css("opacity",1).show(),b.API.stackSlides(b.slides[b.currSlide],b.slides[b.nextSlide],!b.reverse),b.pauseOnHover&&(b.pauseOnHover!==!0&&(c=a(b.pauseOnHover)),c.hover(function(){b.hoverPaused=!0,b.paused||b.API.trigger("cycle-paused",[b])},function(){b.hoverPaused=!1,b.paused||b.API.trigger("cycle-resumed",[b])})),b.timeout&&(b.timeoutId=setTimeout(function(){b.API.prepareTx(!1,!b.reverse)},b.timeout+b.delay)),b._initialized=!0,b.API.updateView(!0),b.container.on("cycle-paused cycle-resumed",function(a){b.container[a.type==="cycle-paused"?"addClass":"removeClass"]("cycle-paused")}),b.API.trigger("cycle-initialized",[b]),b.API.postInitSlideshow()},add:function(b,c){var d=this.opts(),e=d.slideCount,f=!1,g;a(b).each(function(b){var e,f=a(this);c?d.container.prepend(f):d.container.append(f),d.slideCount++,e=d.API.buildSlideOpts(f),c?d.slides=a(f).add(d.slides):d.slides=d.slides.add(f),d.API.initSlide(e,f,--d._maxZ),f.data("cycle.opts",e),d.API.trigger("cycle-slide-added",[d,e,f])}),d.API.updateView(!0),f=d._preInitialized&&e<2&&d.slideCount>=1,f&&(d._initialized?d.timeout&&(g=d.slides.length,d.nextSlide=d.reverse?g-1:1):d.API.initSlideshow())},calcFirstSlide:function(){var a=this.opts(),b;b=parseInt(a.startingSlide||0,10);if(b>=a.slides.length||b<0)b=0;a.currSlide=b,a.reverse?(a.nextSlide=b-1,a.nextSlide<0&&(a.nextSlide=a.slides.length-1)):(a.nextSlide=b+1,a.nextSlide==a.slides.length&&(a.nextSlide=0))},calcNextSlide:function(){var a=this.opts(),b;a.reverse?(b=a.nextSlide-1<0,a.nextSlide=b?a.slideCount-1:a.nextSlide-1,a.currSlide=b?0:a.nextSlide+1):(b=a.nextSlide+1==a.slides.length,a.nextSlide=b?0:a.nextSlide+1,a.currSlide=b?a.slides.length-1:a.nextSlide-1)},calcTx:function(b,d){var e=b,f;return d&&e.manualFx&&(f=a.fn.cycle.transitions[e.manualFx]),f||(f=a.fn.cycle.transitions[e.fx]),f||(f=a.fn.cycle.transitions.fade,c('Transition "'+e.fx+'" not found.  Using fade.')),f},prepareTx:function(a,b){var c=this.opts(),d,e,f,g,h;if(c.slideCount<2){c.timeoutId=0;return}a&&(c.API.stopTransition(),c.busy=!1,clearTimeout(c.timeoutId),c.timeoutId=0);if(c.busy)return;if(c.timeoutId===0&&!a)return;e=c.slides[c.currSlide],f=c.slides[c.nextSlide],g=c.API.getSlideOpts(c.nextSlide),h=c.API.calcTx(g,a),c._tx=h,a&&g.manualSpeed!==undefined&&(g.speed=g.manualSpeed),c.nextSlide!=c.currSlide&&(a||!c.paused&&!c.hoverPaused&&c.timeout)?(c.API.trigger("cycle-before",[g,e,f,b]),h.before&&h.before(g,e,f,b),d=function(){c.busy=!1,h.after&&h.after(g,e,f,b),c.API.trigger("cycle-after",[g,e,f,b]),c.API.queueTransition(g),c.API.updateView(!0)},c.busy=!0,h.transition?h.transition(g,e,f,b,d):c.API.doTransition(g,e,f,b,d),c.API.calcNextSlide(),c.updateView<0&&c.API.updateView()):c.API.queueTransition(g)},doTransition:function(b,c,d,e,f){var g=b,h=a(c),i=a(d),j=function(){i.animate(g.animIn||{opacity:1},g.speed,g.easeIn||g.easing,f)};i.css(g.cssBefore||{}),h.animate(g.animOut||{},g.speed,g.easeOut||g.easing,function(){h.css(g.cssAfter||{}),g.sync||j()}),g.sync&&j()},queueTransition:function(a){var b=this.opts();if(b.nextSlide===0&&--b.loop===0){b.API.log("terminating; loop=0"),b.timeout=0,b.API.trigger("cycle-finished",[b]),b.nextSlide=b.currSlide;return}a.timeout&&(b.timeoutId=setTimeout(function(){b.API.prepareTx(!1,!b.reverse)},a.timeout))},stopTransition:function(){var a=this.opts();a.slides.filter(":animated").length&&(a.slides.stop(!1,!0),a.API.trigger("cycle-transition-stopped",[a])),a._tx&&a._tx.stopTransition&&a._tx.stopTransition(a)},advanceSlide:function(a){var b=this.opts();return clearTimeout(b.timeoutId),b.timeoutId=0,b.nextSlide=b.currSlide+a,b.nextSlide<0?b.nextSlide=b.slides.length-1:b.nextSlide>=b.slides.length&&(b.nextSlide=0),b.API.prepareTx(!0,a>=0),!1},buildSlideOpts:function(b){var e=this.opts(),f,g,h=b.data()||{};for(var i in h)h.hasOwnProperty(i)&&/^cycle[A-Z]+/.test(i)&&(f=h[i],g=i.match(/^cycle(.*)/)[1].replace(/^[A-Z]/,d),c("["+(e.slideCount-1)+"]",g+":",f,"("+typeof f+")"),h[g]=f);h=a.extend({},a.fn.cycle.defaults,e,h),h.slideNum=e.slideCount;try{delete h.API,delete h.slideCount,delete h.currSlide,delete h.nextSlide,delete h.slides}catch(j){}return h},getSlideOpts:function(b){var c=this.opts();b===undefined&&(b=c.currSlide);var d=c.slides[b],e=a(d).data("cycle.opts");return a.extend({},c,e)},initSlide:function(b,c,d){var e=this.opts();c.css(b.slideCss||{}),d>0&&c.css("zIndex",d),isNaN(b.speed)&&(b.speed=a.fx.speeds[b.speed]||a.fx.speeds._default),b.sync||(b.speed=b.speed/2),c.addClass(e.slideClass)},updateView:function(a){var b=this.opts();if(!b._initialized)return;var c=b.API.getSlideOpts(),d=b.slides[b.currSlide];b.slideActiveClass&&b.slides.removeClass(b.slideActiveClass).eq(b.currSlide).addClass(b.slideActiveClass),a&&b.hideNonActive&&b.slides.filter(":not(."+b.slideActiveClass+")").hide(),b.API.trigger("cycle-update-view",[b,c,d])},getComponent:function(b){var c=this.opts(),d=c[b];return typeof d=="string"?/^\s*\>/.test(d)?c.container.find(d):a(d):d.jquery?d:a(d)},stackSlides:function(b,c,d){var e=this.opts();b||(b=e.slides[e.currSlide],c=e.slides[e.nextSlide],d=!e.reverse),a(b).css("zIndex",e.maxZ);var f,g=e.maxZ-2,h=e.slideCount;if(d){for(f=e.currSlide+1;f<h;f++)a(e.slides[f]).css("zIndex",g--);for(f=0;f<e.currSlide;f++)a(e.slides[f]).css("zIndex",g--)}else{for(f=e.currSlide-1;f>=0;f--)a(e.slides[f]).css("zIndex",g--);for(f=h-1;f>e.currSlide;f--)a(e.slides[f]).css("zIndex",g--)}a(c).css("zIndex",e.maxZ-1)},getSlideIndex:function(a){return this.opts().slides.index(a)}},a.fn.cycle.log=c,a.fn.cycle.version=function(){return"Cycle2: "+b},a.fn.cycle.transitions={custom:{},none:{before:function(a,b,c,d){a.API.stackSlides(c,b,d),a.cssBefore={opacity:1,display:"block"}}},fade:{before:function(b,c,d,e){var f=b.API.getSlideOpts(b.nextSlide).slideCss||{};b.API.stackSlides(c,d,e),b.cssBefore=a.extend(f,{opacity:0,display:"block"}),b.animIn={opacity:1},b.animOut={opacity:0}}},fadeout:{before:function(b,c,d,e){var f=b.API.getSlideOpts(b.nextSlide).slideCss||{};b.API.stackSlides(c,d,e),b.cssBefore=a.extend(f,{opacity:1,display:"block"}),b.animOut={opacity:0}}},scrollHorz:{before:function(a,b,c,d){a.API.stackSlides(b,c,d);var e=a.container.css("overflow","hidden").width();a.cssBefore={left:d?e:-e,top:0,opacity:1,display:"block"},a.cssAfter={zIndex:a._maxZ-2,left:0},a.animIn={left:0},a.animOut={left:d?-e:e}}}},a.fn.cycle.defaults={allowWrap:!0,autoSelector:".cycle-slideshow[data-cycle-auto-init!=false]",delay:0,easing:null,fx:"fade",hideNonActive:!0,loop:0,manualFx:undefined,manualSpeed:undefined,maxZ:100,pauseOnHover:!1,reverse:!1,slideActiveClass:"cycle-slide-active",slideClass:"cycle-slide",slideCss:{position:"absolute",top:0,left:0},slides:"> img",speed:500,startingSlide:0,sync:!0,timeout:4e3,updateView:-1},a(document).ready(function(){a(a.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector).cycle()})})(jQuery),function(a){"use strict",a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{autoHeight:0}),a(document).on("cycle-initialized",function(b,c){function h(){c.container.height(c.container.width()/g)}var d=c.autoHeight,e=-1,f,g;d==="calc"||a.type(d)=="number"&&d>=0?(d==="calc"?c.slides.each(function(b){var c=a(this).height();c>e&&(e=c,d=b)}):d>=c.slides.length&&(d=0),f=a(c.slides[d]).clone(),f.removeAttr("id").find("[id]").removeAttr("id"),f.removeAttr("name").find("[name]").removeAttr("name"),f.css({position:"static",visibility:"hidden",display:"block"}).prependTo(c.container).removeClass().addClass("cycle-sentinel cycle-slide"),f.find("*").css("visibility","hidden"),c._sentinel=f):a.type(d)=="string"&&/\d+\:\d+/.test(d)&&(g=d.match(/(\d+)\:(\d+)/),g=g[1]/g[2],a(window).on("resize",h),c._autoHeightOnResize=h,setTimeout(function(){a(window).triggerHandler("resize")},15))}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(b,c){c._sentinel&&c._sentinel.remove(),c._autoHeightOnResize&&a(window).off("resize",c._autoHeightOnResize)})}(jQuery),function(a){"use strict",a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{caption:"> .cycle-caption",captionTemplate:"{{slideNum}} / {{slideCount}}",overlay:"> .cycle-overlay",overlayTemplate:"<div>{{title}}</div><div>{{desc}}</div>"}),a(document).on("cycle-update-view",function(b,c,d,e){var f;a.each(["caption","overlay"],function(){var a=this,b=d[a+"Template"],f=c.API.getComponent(a);f.length&&b?(f.html(c.API.tmpl(b,d,c,e)),f.show()):f.hide()})}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(b,c){var d;a.each(["caption","overlay"],function(){var a=this,b=c[a+"Template"];c[a]&&b&&(d=c.API.getComponent("caption"),d.empty())})})}(jQuery),function(a){"use strict";var b=a.fn.cycle;a.fn.cycle=function(c){var d,e,f,g=a.makeArray(arguments);return a.type(c)=="number"?this.cycle("goto",c):a.type(c)=="string"?this.each(function(){var h;d=c,f=a(this).data("cycle.opts");if(f===undefined){b.log('slideshow must be initialized before sending commands; "'+d+'" ignored');return}d=d=="goto"?"jump":d,e=f.API[d];if(a.isFunction(e))return h=a.makeArray(g),h.shift(),e.apply(f.API,h);b.log("unknown command: ",d)}):b.apply(this,arguments)},a.extend(a.fn.cycle,b),a.extend(b.API,{next:function(){var a=this.opts(),b=a.reverse?-1:1;if(a.allowWrap===!1&&a.currSlide+b>=a.slideCount)return;a.API.advanceSlide(b),a.API.trigger("cycle-next",[a]).log("cycle-next")},prev:function(){var a=this.opts(),b=a.reverse?1:-1;if(a.allowWrap===!1&&a.currSlide+b<0)return;a.API.advanceSlide(b),a.API.trigger("cycle-prev",[a]).log("cycle-prev")},destroy:function(){var a=this.opts();clearTimeout(a.timeoutId),a.timeoutId=0,a.API.stop(),a.API.trigger("cycle-destroyed",[a]).log("cycle-destroyed"),a.container.removeData("cycle.opts")},jump:function(a){var b,c=this.opts(),d=parseInt(a,10);if(isNaN(d)||d<0||d>=c.slides.length){c.API.log("goto: invalid slide index: "+d);return}if(d==c.currSlide){c.API.log("goto: skipping, already on slide",d);return}c.nextSlide=d,clearTimeout(c.timeoutId),c.timeoutId=0,c.API.log("goto: ",d," (zero-index)"),b=c.currSlide<c.nextSlide,c.API.prepareTx(!0,b)},stop:function(){var b=this.opts(),c=b.container;clearTimeout(b.timeoutId),b.timeoutId=0,b.API.stopTransition(),b.pauseOnHover&&(b.pauseOnHover!==!0&&(c=a(b.pauseOnHover)),c.off("mouseenter mouseleave")),b.API.trigger("cycle-stopped",[b]).log("cycle-stopped")},pause:function(){var a=this.opts();a.paused=!0,a.API.trigger("cycle-paused",[a]).log("cycle-paused")},resume:function(){var a=this.opts();a.paused=!1,a.API.trigger("cycle-resumed",[a]).log("cycle-resumed")},reinit:function(){var a=this.opts();a.API.destroy(),a.container.cycle()},remove:function(b){var c=this.opts(),d,e,f=[],g=1;for(var h=0;h<c.slides.length;h++)d=c.slides[h],h==b?e=d:(f.push(d),a(d).data("cycle.opts").slideNum=g,g++);e&&(c.slides=a(f),c.slideCount--,a(e).remove(),b==c.currSlide&&c.API.advanceSlide(1),c.API.trigger("cycle-slide-removed",[c,b,e]).log("cycle-slide-removed"),c.API.updateView())}}),a(document).on("click.cycle","[data-cycle-cmd]",function(b){b.preventDefault();var c=a(this),d=c.data("cycle-cmd"),e=c.data("cycle-context")||".cycle-slideshow";a(e).cycle(d,c.data("cycle-arg"))})}(jQuery),function(a){function b(b,c){var d;if(b._hashFence){b._hashFence=!1;return}d=window.location.hash.substring(1),b.slides.each(function(e){if(a(this).data("cycle-hash")==d)return c===!0?b.startingSlide=e:(b.nextSlide=e,b.API.prepareTx(!0,!1)),!1})}"use strict",a(document).on("cycle-pre-initialize",function(c,d){b(d,!0),d._onHashChange=function(){b(d,!1)},a(window).on("hashchange",d._onHashChange)}),a(document).on("cycle-update-view",function(a,b,c){c.hash&&(b._hashFence=!0,window.location.hash=c.hash)}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(b,c){c._onHashChange&&a(window).off("hashchange",c._onHashChange)})}(jQuery),function(a){"use strict",a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{loader:!1}),a(document).on("cycle-bootstrap",function(b,c){function e(b,e){function h(b){var h;c.loader=="wait"?(f.push(b),g===0&&(f.sort(i),d.apply(c.API,[f,e]),c.container.removeClass("cycle-loading"))):(h=a(c.slides[c.currSlide]),d.apply(c.API,[b,e]),h.show(),c.container.removeClass("cycle-loading"))}function i(a,b){return a.data("index")-b.data("index")}var f=[];b=a(b);var g=b.length;b.hide().appendTo("body").each(function(b){function l(){--i===0&&(--g,h(j))}var i=0,j=a(this),k=j.is("img")?j:j.find("img");j.data("index",b),k=k.filter(":not(.cycle-loader-ignore)");if(!k.length){--g,f.push(j);return}i=k.length,k.each(function(){this.complete?l():a(this).load(function(){l()}).error(function(){--i===0&&(c.API.log("slide skipped; img not loaded:",this.src),--g===0&&c.loader=="wait"&&d.apply(c.API,[f,e]))})})}),g&&c.container.addClass("cycle-loading")}var d;if(!c.loader)return;d=c.API.add,c.API.add=e})}(jQuery),function(a){function b(b,c,d){var e,f=b.API.getComponent("pager");f.each(function(){var f=a(this);if(c.pagerTemplate){var g=b.API.tmpl(c.pagerTemplate,c,b,d[0]);e=a(g).appendTo(f)}else e=f.children().eq(b.slideCount-1);e.on(b.pagerEvent,function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.API.page(f,a.currentTarget)})})}function c(a,b){var c=this.opts(),d=a.children().index(b),e=d,f=c.currSlide<e;if(c.currSlide==e)return;c.nextSlide=e,c.API.prepareTx(!0,f),c.API.trigger("cycle-pager-activated",[c,a,b])}"use strict",a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{pager:"> .cycle-pager",pagerActiveClass:"cycle-pager-active",pagerEvent:"click.cycle",pagerTemplate:"<span>&bull;</span>"}),a(document).on("cycle-bootstrap",function(a,c,d){d.buildPagerLink=b}),a(document).on("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b,d,e){b.pager&&(b.API.buildPagerLink(b,d,e),b.API.page=c)}),a(document).on("cycle-slide-removed",function(b,c,d,e){if(c.pager){var f=c.API.getComponent("pager");f.each(function(){var b=a(this);a(b.children()[d]).remove()})}}),a(document).on("cycle-update-view",function(b,c,d){var e;c.pager&&(e=c.API.getComponent("pager"),e.each(function(){a(this).children().removeClass(c.pagerActiveClass).eq(c.currSlide).addClass(c.pagerActiveClass)}))}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(a,b){var c;b.pager&&b.pagerTemplate&&(c=b.API.getComponent("pager"),c.empty())})}(jQuery),function(a){"use strict",a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{next:"> .cycle-next",nextEvent:"click.cycle",disabledClass:"disabled",prev:"> .cycle-prev",prevEvent:"click.cycle",swipe:!1}),a(document).on("cycle-initialized",function(a,b){b.API.getComponent("next").off(b.nextEvent).on(b.nextEvent,function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.API.next()}),b.API.getComponent("prev").off(b.prevEvent).on(b.prevEvent,function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.API.prev()});if(b.swipe){var c=b.swipeVert?"swipeUp.cycle":"swipeLeft.cycle swipeleft.cycle",d=b.swipeVert?"swipeDown.cycle":"swipeRight.cycle swiperight.cycle";b.container.on(c,function(a){b.API.next()}),b.container.on(d,function(){b.API.prev()})}}),a(document).on("cycle-update-view",function(a,b,c,d){if(b.allowWrap)return;var e=b.disabledClass,f=b.API.getComponent("next"),g=b.API.getComponent("prev"),h=b._prevBoundry||0,i=b._nextBoundry||b.slideCount-1;b.currSlide==i?f.addClass(e).prop("disabled",!0):f.removeClass(e).prop("disabled",!1),b.currSlide===h?g.addClass(e).prop("disabled",!0):g.removeClass(e).prop("disabled",!1)}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(b,c){a(c.next).off(c.nextEvent),a(c.prev).off(c.prevEvent),c.container.off("swipeleft.cycle swiperight.cycle swipeLeft.cycle swipeRight.cycle swipeUp.cycle swipeDown.cycle")})}(jQuery),function(a){"use strict",a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{progressive:!1}),a(document).on("cycle-pre-initialize",function(b,c){if(!c.progressive)return;var d=c.API,e=d.next,f=d.prev,g=d.prepareTx,h,i=a.type(c.progressive);if(i=="array")h=c.progressive;else if(a.isFunction(c.progressive))h=c.progressive(c);else if(i=="string"){h=a(c.progressive).html();if(!a.trim(h))return;try{h=a.parseJSON(h)}catch(j){d.log("error parsing progressive slides",j);return}}g&&(d.prepareTx=function(a,b){var d,e;if(a||h.length===0){g.apply(c.API,[a,b]);return}b&&c.currSlide==c.slideCount-1?(e=h[0],h=h.slice(1),c.container.one("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b){b.API.advanceSlide(1)}),c.API.add(e)):!b&&c.currSlide===0?(d=h.length-1,e=h[d],h=h.slice(0,d),c.container.one("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b){b.currSlide=1,b.API.advanceSlide(-1)}),c.API.add(e,!0)):g.apply(c.API,[a,b])}),e&&(d.next=function(){var a=this.opts();if(h.length&&a.currSlide==a.slideCount-1){var b=h[0];h=h.slice(1),a.container.one("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b){e.apply(b.API),b.container.removeClass("cycle-loading")}),a.container.addClass("cycle-loading"),a.API.add(b)}else e.apply(a.API)}),f&&(d.prev=function(){var a=this.opts();if(h.length&&a.currSlide===0){var b=h.length-1,c=h[b];h=h.slice(0,b),a.container.one("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b){b.currSlide=1,b.API.advanceSlide(-1),b.container.removeClass("cycle-loading")}),a.container.addClass("cycle-loading"),a.API.add(c,!0)}else f.apply(a.API)})})}(jQuery),function(a){"use strict",a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{tmplRegex:"{{((.)?.*?)}}"}),a.extend(a.fn.cycle.API,{tmpl:function(b,c){var d=new RegExp(c.tmplRegex||a.fn.cycle.defaults.tmplRegex,"g"),e=a.makeArray(arguments);return e.shift(),b.replace(d,function(b,c){var d,f,g,h,i=c.split(".");for(d=0;d<e.length;d++){g=e[d];if(i.length>1){h=g;for(f=0;f<i.length;f++)g=h,h=h[i[f]]||c}else h=g[c];if(a.isFunction(h))return h.apply(g,e);if(h!==undefined&&h!==null&&h!=c)return h}return c})}})}(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you give us some more?  possibly code, is it run by javascript? Css? etc.  There's very little to go on

Comment: sorry. Ive been stuck on this all day.
Its run by CSS, the little bit of javascript in it doesnt control what I'm trying to accomplish. Im going to post the code I think is causing the nav bar to not be visible and appear after the menu icon is selected.

Comment: Going by what you're saying about the menu button, it seems as if the default configuration for your menu is set to `display: none;`. Try to set it to be visible

Comment: I've done that. For whatever reason its not working. I assumed that would be the clear answer but its not.

Comment: Would you mind posting your CSS and javascript as well?  We can dig in farther if you do

Comment: @ntgCleaner Ive posted the javascript and the css was too long to post apparently. But that can be seen using developer tools at the link [link](http://thehappybit.com/demo/bigfoot/)

Answer (score 1):

in layout.css

To make menu always visible:

```
.nav-wrapper { -khtml-opacity: 0; -moz-opacity: 0; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; visibility: hidden; -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out; transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; padding-top: 38px; padding-bottom: 38px; background-color: #fff; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); }
```

change with

```
.nav-wrapper { -khtml-opacity: 1; -moz-opacity: 1; opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"; visibility: visible; }
```

To disable logo:

```
#logo { -khtml-opacity: 1; -moz-opacity: 1; opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"; -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear; -ms-transition: opacity 0.15s linear; transition: opacity 0.15s linear; float: left; margin-left: 20px; -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
```

change with

```
#logo { -khtml-opacity: 0; -moz-opacity: 0; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Wordpress theme, it seems that you just need to change the CSS of `.nav-wrapper`.  Take off all of the opacity stuff and all of the filter/transition stuff.  Make it look just like this:

```
.nav-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 38px;
    padding-bottom: 38px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

Then the menu will always be there.

Comment: That had no effect. Im going to post the css and the javascript. Honestly I'm not sure what command is telling the navigation to act in that way. Im also not sure what css to attach but once again ill look for where I think the problem is coming from. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @user2966504 Try going into the "theme.js" and on line 23, change `thb_toggling_menu = false;` to `thb_toggling_menu = true;` and let me know what that does.

Comment: @user2966504 Another thing to try is to give the `body` an extra class of `nav-active`.  That seems to be what is determining whether or not the nav shows.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-wrapper
{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 38px;
    padding-bottom: 38px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

The above example forgot the opacity, this does screw up the mobile support though.

Answer (score 0):

in the header.php just replace the code from this part with...

```
  <div class="wrapper">
                        <?php
                            $logo = thb_get_option('main_logo');
                            $logo_2x = thb_get_option('main_logo_retina');

                            if( !empty($logo['id']) && !empty($logo_2x['id']) ) : ?>
                            <?php $logo_metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($logo['id']); ?>
                            <style>
                                @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
                                    #logo {
                                        background-image: url('<?php echo thb_image_get_size($logo_2x['id'], 'full'); ?>');
                                        background-size: <?php echo $logo_metadata['width']; ?>px, <?php echo $logo_metadata['height']; ?>px;
                                    }

                                    #logo img { visibility: hidden; }
                                }
                            </style>

                            <?php endif;
                        ?>
                        <h1 id="logo">
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
                                <?php if( isset($logo['id']) && $logo['id'] != '' ) : ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo thb_image_get_size($logo['id'], 'full'); ?>" alt="">
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </h1>

                        <?php thb_nav_before(); ?>

                        <?php
$isMobile = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Mobile');

if ($isMobile) {
    $id = "nav-trigger";
} else {
    $id = "nav-dodge";
}
?>

    <a href="#" id="<?= $id ?>">m</a>



                            <nav id="main-nav" class="main-navigation primary">
                                <?php thb_nav_start(); ?>

                                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

                                <?php thb_nav_end(); ?>
                            </nav>



    <div class="nav-wrapper">
```